# Disable Cache but enable on subdomain

Tags: html, asp.net, caching

Trying to avoid my main page using cache generated by /sub.
Main page is in html, getting code from flask. and i have removed some "levers" to hide information for non members. /sub with member content is in .asp.

Doing a fresh load without cache stored: the web page hides the lever, but when i enter /sub  toggle the "lever" and logout (redirected to main). the "lever" is not there but it is toggled on there too.

tried this in html: (the bottom 2 were already included in sentrylogin`s login form but did not effect the "lever")

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

and :

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

in .asp this is already implemented :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

basicly i want the .html file to ignore all cache, dont make any, dont get any. if that works. are there some better commands?

Comment: It will be easy for you if u handle this on back end
 `var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;` will give you url of current page check if contains sub domain or not 


`Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`
        `Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));`
       
 `Response.Cache.SetNoStore();`
use above code if its not sub domain it will clear all the  cache

Comment: What i can do backend is limited. i can only use .js. I`m fairly green on this but that code looks like c#? 

Been googling some and was concidering using .js "localStorage.clear()"
but i would only want to have that on one of my html file. is that possible?
or directly into html. i found a way to make it work on button: onclick but have no idea how to get it done on page load.

Comment: yes it is in c# which language you are using